# installing specflow for vs2013 mssing TechTalk.SpecFlow reference

Tags: specflow

I installed Specflow using the Download button 
[from the VS2013 specflow page](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/90ac3587-7466-4155-b591-2cd4cc4401bc)

I added a feature to my Specs project using  Add New Item and Choosing SpecFlow Feature File

When I build the project I get 
Error   1   The type or namespace name 'TechTalk' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I also get an error mentioning that NUnit is missing.

Where would I find the files to reference and how do I check they are correct to go with TechTalk.Specflow 1.9.3.0 ?

Comment: Have you downloaded the nuget package? Its probably the best way to get the latest files - Install-Package SpecFlow

Comment: i did try that, but have been going around in circles... SpecFlow for VS2013 is not the same as for VS2012

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to visual studio package manager console.

To install specflow for NUnit, type

```
Install-Package SpecFlow.NUnit
```

This will install all the required packages and a correctly configured app.config to work with NUnit.

If you instead resolved all the references by hand, then you would still have to construct the app config correctly.  Finding the right config for MSTest or NUnit can take a little while to get right so it is better to just use the nuget package.

Comment: Building OK now... however Test Explorer doesnt display the tests

Comment: I pretty much don't use VS test explorer any more so can't help directly.  Since this is a separate issue, perhaps search the site for answers to similar issues and if you can't find any, post another question.  Good luck!

Comment: Also the generated code indicates that the spec flow version has changed. It was previously 1.9.3 now it has reverted to 1.9.0.77

Comment: I also managed to get it working with NUnit by installing the Nunit Test Adapter from Package Manager